# Авторизация на сайте с помощью CURL

Tags: php, curl

Всем привет. Пытаюсь пройти авторизацию на сайте https://www.farpost.ru/ , но он просит подтверждения через смс, помогите пожалуйста.

```
<?
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
include "Snoopy/Snoopy.class.php";

function URIRequest($url, $method='GET', $params=FALSE, $user=FALSE, $pass=FALSE, $refferer=FALSE) {

    $ch = curl_init();

    if ($method == 'POST') {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); // set POST method
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params); // add POST fields
    }

    if(strpos($url,'https://') !== FALSE){
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    }
    if ($user) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $user.':'.$pass);
    }
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); // установить запрашиваемый URL

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/cookiefile3.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/cookiefile3.txt');

    $refferer = "https://www.farpost.ru/vladivostok";

    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $refferer); // если требуется передача HTTP_REFERER
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36" );

    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); // HTTP заголовки ответа включать в возвращаемый результат
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); // возвратить результат обработки в переменную а не на STDOUT
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); // если будут редиректы - следовать за ними
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 120); // таймаут соединения - 2 минуты
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 0);  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);

    $result = curl_exec ($ch); // выполнить запрос
//    curl_close($ch);
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);

    return $result;
}

$params = array();

$params['radio'] = 'sign';
$params['sign'] = 'number';
$params['password'] = 'password';

$ret = URIRequest('http://www.farpost.ru/sign?return=%2Fvladivostok%2F', 'POST', $params, FALSE, FALSE, 'http://www.farpost.ru/vladivostok');

var_dump($ret);
```

Comment: Если есть возможность получить сгенерированный код для смс и известен URL обработки SMS - просто делаете дополнительный запрос на него с кодом из смс

Comment: В том то и дело, что не знаю как получить код на телефон, т.к в ручную он авторизацию проходит без проблем и никогда не просит подтверждения.